# Database design of a one-to-many relationship in a model

Tags: c#, database-design

I have  model, say a menu, with an ID, a name and several meals and I have another model, say a meal, with an ID and a name.  So the Menu Model would be like this:

```
public class Menu{
private int ID,
private string Name,
private List<Meal> meal
}
```

My model Meal,

```
public class Menu{
private int ID,
private string Name
}
```

So I want to implement this one to many relationship in my database.
So I thought of doing it like this:

```
Menu: menu_id, name     #the "one" side
Meal:  meal_id, name, menu_id  # the "many" side
```

But I think this is not the correct way of doing it. I am really confuse about how to implement the Menu/Meal relationship as written in the models, in the database.

Comment: In your current model, a meal can only belong to one menu.  I would make it a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Oh ok. So I did a many to many relationship. But for my meal model in C# do I need to make any modification?